# Converting a long nested if and or formula into vba case

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, nested

I have a nestled `If And Or` formula that I am trying to convert into probably a `Case` formula using VBA (or any other suggestion would be great), but I am a beginner and not sure how.  The reason is that this formula currently is in every cell `AG12:ACG500` and takes up so much memory that the spreadsheet is extremely slow.

Basically, I am trying to match the date in column `Z12:Z500` (Outage Month Start) to the date in Row `AG6:ACG6` (DATES), then looking in column `C12:C500` (ACTV_NAME)... which provides the output of either `R, S, L, MR, MS, ML, ?R, ?S or ?L` in the cell where the two dates (column Z and row 6) intersect .. this should coincide with the where the Gantt Chart bar starts .. I do not need any help with the Gantt chart bars/color coding .. I just need help basically labeling them with the fore-mentioned.

`=IF(OR($Z12="",$AA12=""),"",IF(AND(AG$6=$Z12,$Z12<>"",$C12="Relay",$L12="No"),"R",IF(AND(AG$6=$Z12,$Z12<>"",$C12="Substation",$L12="No"),"S",IF(AND(AG$6=$Z12,$Z12<>"",$C12="Line",$L12="No"),"L",IF(AND(AG$6=$Z12,$Z12<>"",$C12="Relay",$L12="YES"),"MR",IF(AND(AG$6=$Z12,$Z12<>"",$C12="Substation",$L12="YES"),"MS",IF(AND($AF$6=$Z12,$Z12<>"",$C12="Line",$L12="YES"),"ML",IF(AND(AG$6=$Z12,$Z12<>"",$C12="Relay",$L12="Maybe"),"?R",IF(AND(AG$6=$Z12,$Z12<>"",$C12="Substation",$L12="Maybe"),"?S",IF(AND($AF$6=$Z12,$Z12<>"",$C12="Line",$L12="Maybe"),"?L",""))))))))))`

Answer (score 0):

Your formula can be simplified to:

```
=IF(OR($Z12="",$AA12=""),"",IF(AND(AG$6=$Z12,$Z12<>""),IF($L12 = "YES","M" & LEFT($C12,1),IF($L12 = "Maybe","?" & LEFT($C12,1),LEFT($C12,1))),""))
```

Comment: thanks this is great.  However, I am still challenged with having this formulas in a 182,500 cells which takes up tons of memory and slows down the spreadsheet extremely.  I am looking for a way to do convert it into a macro, but not using the ".formula=" method, but probably using CASE or some other method, but I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: @user7053814 usually you will not get people here to simply write vba for you.  Since you provided a formula I responded with a formula.  I would suggest using the logic of the above formula to try and create a routine that loops through each row to place just the value.  When you get stuck return with the code you have tried and tell us where it breaks.  It is usually frowned on here to ask for vba help without any attempt at vba showing.

Answer (score 0):

### Converting single formula into a routine that loops

**This is Scott Craner's simplified version of your formula, converted into a routine that will loop through all the cells in `AG12:ACG500` and check each cell for their intersecting criteria.**

*I am not able to test this code because I have no data set to base it off of. That being said, I'm not sure that it will perform in the way you desire. Let me know if it works for you.*

```
Sub compareDates()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Dim dataRange As Range: Set dataRange = ws.Range("AG12:ACG500")
    Dim oMS As Range, aN As Range, idk As Range, d As Range
    Dim yNM As Range, myCell As Range, myRow As Long, myCol As Long

    For Each myCell In dataRange
        myRow = myCell.Row
        myCol = myCell.Column

        Set oMS = ws.Range("Z" & myRow)  'Outage Month Start
        Set aN = ws.Range("C" & myRow)   'ACTV_NAME
        Set idk = ws.Range("AA" & myRow) 'not sure what AA is for
        Set d = ws.Cells(6, myCol)  'DATES
        Set yNM = ws.Range("L" & myRow)  'yes no maybe

        If oMS.Value = "" Or idk.Value = "" Then
            myCell.Value = ""
        ElseIf d.Value = oMS.Value And oMS.Value <> "" Then
            If UCase(yNM.Value) = UCase("Yes") Then
                myCell.Value = "M" & Left(aN.Value, 1)
            ElseIf UCase(yNM.Value) = UCase("Maybe") Then
                myCell.Value = "?" & Left(aN.Value, 1)
            Else: myCell.Value = Left(aN.Value, 1)
            End If
        Else: myCell.Value = ""
        End If
    Next myCell
End Sub
```